# There must be a better way - change search as user input changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, filter

I have a search filter that hides s as the user enters text into a form input. I need it to be dynamic, so that as the user changes their input, the filter refreshes. I accomplished this by having the filter clear on every keyup, but that causes the filter to be delayed and to flash when a word is typed quickly into the filter. You can see what I mean here:

http://cambridgefellows.com/directory-of-fellows/

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').val('');
   $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').keyup(function() { 
    var searchFilterVal = $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').val();
    searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.replace(/ /g, '-');
    searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.toLowerCase();
    $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');

    if(searchFilterVal == '') {
        $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
    } else {

        $('tr.fellows').each(function() {
        var pattern = $(this).attr('class');    // the pattern to be matched 
        var match = pattern.match(searchFilterVal);//If pattern matches it returns the match

        if(!match) {
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hide');

            } else {
            }
        });
    }
   });


$('#searchForm').bind("keyup keypress", function(e) {
 var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (code  == 13) {               
    e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
});



});
```

I think there must be an easier way to handle this so that the filter dynamically updates as the user enter or alters their search text. Can someone more experienced than me look at this an enlighten me to the obvious thing that I'm overlooking? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: In this situation it is normal to clear/start a timer on each keyup. The code then runs after a pause of inactivity. No effect on the keystrokes then.

Comment: I see what you mean. Why can you not have copy of the data non visible that you filter and display only when the filter has been applied, then the user would only see filtered results and not the clear/unfiltered results each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

```
var timer;
$('input[name=searchFilterInput]').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var searchFilterVal = $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').val();
        searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.replace(/ /g, '-');
        searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.toLowerCase();
        $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');

        if(searchFilterVal == '') {
            $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
        } else {

            $('tr.fellows').each(function() {
            var pattern = $(this).attr('class');    // the pattern to be matched 
            var match = pattern.match(searchFilterVal);//If pattern matches it returns the match

            if(!match) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hide');

                } else {
                }
            });
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

That way whenever a user hits the next key, the timeout will be cleared from the previous keypress and the code will only execute for the current keypress.

Reduce the milliseconds if you feel it's not updating fast enough.

Comment: Awesome - this looks like exactly what I need. I knew there must be something like this - thanks so much! I'll give it a shot.